# MWS Amazon Shipping Fee Report _GET_FBA_ESTIMATED_FBA_FEES_TXT_DATA_

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am going to extract fees details (Amazone shipping fees and Amazone referral fees) from Amazon and store in a database. I am getting all data that i need with **GET_FBA_ESTIMATED_FBA_FEES_TXT_DATA** Report type, but i can't find a way, how to associate each fee to country. From report i have bunch of arrays with data for all EU countries. That's how it's looks like:

- "sku" => "111111"
- "fnsku" => "111111"
- "asin" => "111111"
- "product-name" => "Some name"
- "product-group" => "Baby"
- "brand" => "xxx"
- "fulfilled-by" => "Amazon"
- "has-local-inventory" => "true"
- "your-price" => "12.99"
- "sales-price" => "12.99"
- "longest-side" => "33.0"
- "median-side" => "18.0"
- "shortest-side" => "6.0"
- "length-and-girth" => "81.0"
- "unit-of-dimension" => "centimeters"
- "item-package-weight" => "300.01"
- "unit-of-weight" => "grams"
- "product-size-weight-band" => "StandardParcel"
- "currency" => "EUR"
- "estimated-fee-total" => "4.90"
- **"estimated-referral-fee-per-unit" => "1.95"**
- "estimated-variable-closing-fee" => "0.00"
- **"expected-domestic-fulfilment-fee-per-unit" => "2.95"**

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to specify MarketplaceId in ReportRequest.